# sapui5 fiori xml view how to add the BulletChart

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5, sap-fiori

i am coding in fiori (sap web ide) and i have a lack of understanding:

```
<mvc:View
xmlns="sap.m"
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" controllerName="test.view.Detail">
<Page id="detailPage" navButtonPress="onNavBack" title="{i18n&gt;detailTitle}" showNavButton="{device&gt;/isPhone}">
    <content>
        <ObjectHeader id="detailHeader" title="{SelectedOption}" introActive="false" titleActive="false" iconActive="false">
            <customData id="customData3">
                <core:CustomData id="coreCustomData3" key="sapDtResourcePath" value="ClaimingHeader"></core:CustomData>
            </customData>
            <attributes id="detailAttributes">
                <ObjectAttribute id="attribute" text="{i18n&gt;detailText}" active="false"></ObjectAttribute>
            </attributes>
            <firstStatus id="detailStatus">
                <ObjectStatus id="status" text="{SelectedOption}">
                    <customData id="customData4">
                        <core:CustomData id="coreCustomData4" key="sapDtResourcePath" value="ClaimingHeader"></core:CustomData>
                    </customData>
                </ObjectStatus>
            </firstStatus>
        </ObjectHeader>
        <IconTabBar id="idIconTabBar" expanded="{device&gt;/isNoPhone}">
            <customData id="customData5">
                <core:CustomData id="coreCustomData5" key="sapDtResourcePath" value="ClaimingHeader"></core:CustomData>
            </customData>
            <items id="detailsItems">
                <IconTabFilter id="iconTabFilter1" key="selfInfo" icon="sap-icon://calendar">
                    <content>
                        <f:SimpleForm id="iconTabFilter1form" minWidth="1024" editable="false" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout" labelSpanL="3" labelSpanM="3" emptySpanL="4" emptySpanM="4" columnsL="1">
                            <f:content>
```

at the bottom of the code, i want to include this sample code from sapui5 sdk:
[Code: Bullet Micro Chart](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.suite.ui.commons.sample.BulletChart/code)

the problem is, that the code of the BulletChart starts with

```
<core:View controllerName="sap.suite.ui.commons.sample.BulletChart.BulletChart" xmlns="sap.suite.ui.commons" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
```

my problem is, that it doesnt work, if i add this core:View.. inside of mvc:View.. and/or its the other controller, controllerName="sap.suite.ui.commons.sample.BulletChart.BulletChart, which in want to put inside mvc:view , where there is already a controller.

can someone help me and explain me, how to put this BulletChart at this place?

thanks for help! Screenshot on Imageshack what i want to do @ the link below.

[Screenshot on Imageshack what i want to do](http://imageshack.com/a/img673/7559/35wJzB.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inconsistency between documented guidelines and project templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744224/inconsistency-between-documented-guidelines-and-project-templates)

Comment: `<core:View>` inside `<mvc:View>` cannot work. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73532531/5846045

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do the way described below:

Add **xmlns:commons="sap.suite.ui.commons"** to your XML

```
<mvc:View
xmlns="sap.m"
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" 
xmlns:commons="sap.suite.ui.commons"
controllerName="test.view.Detail">
```

then add inside the page content: Notice that we need to have proper namespace depending on **xmlns** declaration

```
<commons:BulletChart size="XS" scale="M" targetValue="100" forecastValue="110" class="marginTopLeft" press="press">
  <commons:actual>
    <commons:BulletChartData value="120" color="Good"/>
  </commons:actual>
  <commons:thresholds>
    <commons:BulletChartData value="0" color="Error"/>
    <commons:BulletChartData value="50" color="Critical"/>
    <commons:BulletChartData value="150" color="Critical"/>
    <commons:BulletChartData value="200" color="Error"/>
  </commons:thresholds>
</commons:BulletChart>
```