# Inconsistency between documented guidelines and project templates

Tags: sapui5

When I look at the [Developer Guide](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/1409791afe4747319a3b23a1e2fc7064) on the SAPUI5 website this is how they declare an XML view:

```xml
<mvc:View
   xmlns="sap.m"
   xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" controllerName="">
</mvc:View>
```

And a controller is defined like this:

```js
sap.ui.define([
   "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function (Controller) {
   "use strict";
   return Controller.extend("", {
   });
});
```

However, when I create an SAPUI5 project in Eclipse and use the option *New* > *SAPUI5 Application Development* > *View*, it creates a view and a controller that look like this:

```xml
<core:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m"
        controllerName="" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
</core:View>
```

```js
sap.ui.controller("", {
});
```

On one hand, creating a view in the above manner saves me from typing the basic syntax every time. Yet on the other hand, the syntax in the developer guide (especially the controller) looks more organized to the eye.

Is there a particular reason why I should use one or the other syntax? Or can I use either approach without any difference in programming?

I am using v1.32 for development.

Comment: As mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/73532531/5846045, the question which approach to use is clarified. Please consider accepting an answer to let others know that this Q&A is resolved.

Answer (score 3):

The first syntax (`sap.ui.define`) is the preferred syntax. It is also known as AMD (*Async Module Declaration*) syntax (see [this Wiki article for more information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition)). It wraps the module (a *controller* in your case) in a function call which enables

- clear and easy to read declaration of the module
- asynchronous invocation of the module (once all dependencies are loaded)

One library that implements this syntax is RequireJS, which is also embedded into SAPUI5 (and OpenUI5 ofc).

In their documentation about *control libraries*, the SAPUI5 team also recommends the AMD syntax (see [here](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/docs/controllibraries.md#developing-a-control-inside-a-library)). All controls in the `sap.m` and `sap.ui` package (that I've checked) use the AMD syntax.

You can also read [this interesting blog post from DJ Adams](http://pipetree.com/qmacro/blog/2015/07/an-introduction-to-sap-ui-define/).

---

However it is nowhere stated (afaik) that the second syntax is deprecated. But keep in mind that it's auto generated by Eclipse because it (the UI5 plugin) is rarely maintained and therefore not up to date (they prefer developing with `Node.js` + `grunt` + `Sublime/Visual Studio Code/etc`.).

There you can get shorter paths for your dependencies by doing `var Controller = sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller` (after you `required` the module)

Answer (score 0):

For the syntax of the view, it'll help if you understand it.

To declare an XML **namespace**, you need to use the following syntax :

```
xmlns:<namespace>="<library the namespace refers to>"
```

The goal of the namespace is to provide an easy and convenient way of referring to a specific library without typing out its name. In this case :

```
<mvc:View
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" controllerName="">
</mvc:View>
```

the *mvc:View* component refers to the *View* class of the *sap.ui.core.mvc* library. *mvc:View* is the equivalent of *sap.ui.core.mvc.View*. You can name your namespace however you want.

The very first thing you declare in your XML view is the **container** for your view. This is the component which will contain all the other components of the view - the root component of the view. You can use components of different libraries as containers for your view. In this example, you are using the *View* component of your *sap.ui.core.mvc* library. In the following example:

```
<core:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m"
    controllerName="" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
</core:View>
```

You are using the *View* component of your *sap.ui.core* library.

The following line:

```
xmlns="sap.m"
```

indicates the default library. This is the library referred to by components declared without a namespace. If later on in my view, I declare the following component:

```
<Input id="myinput"></Input>
```

The UI5 library will load the Input class from the default library, here *sap.m*.

Essentially, there is only one syntax for an XML view:

```
<myNamespace:myContainerComponent
    xmlns="<my.default.library>"
    xmlns:<myFirstNamespace>="my.namespace.library"
    <!-- more if needed -->
    controllerName="my.controller.name">

    <!-- All your other components -->

</myNamespace:myContainerComponent>
```

I do not know enough about the possible controller syntaxes to be able to explain them. I will let someone more knowledgeable than I explain those further.

Hope this helps and makes things clearer for you.

Answer (score 0):

- `<core:View ...>` is simply wrong. Instead, write `<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" ...>`. For more information, see the replies and links from this GitHub issue ["View class doesn't exist in the 'sap.ui.core' namespace"](https://github.com/SAP/ui5-language-assistant/issues/462).
- [`sap.ui.controller`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui#methods/sap.ui.controller) is a deprecated API. The replacement is mentioned in the linked method description.

*Templates* / *generators* can be outdated too and thus, unfortunately, don't always follow best practices. No matter which tool or IDE you use to generate code, please double-check with the documented guidelines.